# How to write a generic method findTableRowBy() in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

As you can see from below simple table, find table column with text equals "January" is simple: "tr/td[text()='January']"
But the td may get complex as it may contains nested elements. So we'd better provide another By parameter.

My question is how to write a generic method that can perform this search. I have one below, but not good, findTableRowsBy(  1, By.xpath( "text()='January'" ) ) will lead to exception. Anybody could help me polish this method? Thanks very much.

```
public List<WebElement> findTableRowsBy( int column, By theBy )
{
    By by = By.xpath( "tbody[1]/tr/td[" + column + "]" );
    List<WebElement> cols = table.findElements( by );
    List<WebElement> rows = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    for( WebElement e : cols )
    {
        List<WebElement> eles = e.findElements( theBy );
        if( eles.isEmpty() )
            continue;
        if( eles.size() == 1 )
            rows.add( eles.get( 0 ) );
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Knowing the stack trace of the exception might help avoiding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you could also use the following xpath:

```
//td[contains(text(), "January")]
```

I guess you should be able to find the proper td even if it has nested elements.

Comment: Thanks, Good to know there is a contains() function in XPath :), in this situation, how could i find all rows that with column 2 contain the text "January"?

Comment: I guess the XPath you should be searching for in this case is: //tr/td[contains(text(), "January")]. That will give you the all matching webelements that you can then loop through.